# Actual warps execution sequential or in parallel?

Tags: cuda

If we have configured 256 threads/block for a SM, then total would be 3 blocks/SM (considering maximum 768 threads/SM). Now total warps/block would be 256/32 = 8 and thus 8*3 = 24 warps/SM. So will these 8 warps in blocks will be executed sequentially or in parallel and 24 warps in SM will execute sequentially or in parallel?
As it is already cleared that at any time 3 blocks can be executed by SM(in parallel).

Comment: There isn't a single answer to this question, it depends on what hardware generation you are asking about. So which hardware do you want to know about? Also, given all modern architectures are pipelined, what do you really mean by "sequential" and "parallel" execution?

Comment: @talonmies: Actually above i asked about compute capability 1.x, but actually I want to know this warp and block execution for devices with compute capabilities 1.x and 2.x. Thus I want to know that in actual, how these warps and blocks are executed, as it is said that at any time 8 blocks can be executed(by above configuration of threads) and also i have read somewhere that SM executes and schedules warp according to priority; so my question is that: does not all warps of all 8 blocks are executed in parallel as all blocks are executed in same time?

Comment: I must say that you question is quite cryptic, I read it several times and I am not sure I understood it completely. On 1.x devices, one warp is executed on an SM at a time (and a pair of warps on 2.x devices) But, as @talonmies said, the hardware is pipelined, i.e., there exist instructions from different warps at different stages of the SM's pipeline at the same time. Perhaps what you mean is *active warps*: that is, a pool of warps that are ready to execute. The hardware chooses some warp based on its priotity (like aging) and throws it on the pipeline..

Comment: @asm    : thanks for your reply, yes actually the concept is cryptic for me, I'm getting little confused about parallel execution of blocks  and sequential process of warp execution. 
Please let me know, am I understood right: the active warps are selected by the hardware and those warps are in pipeline to get?

Answer (score 2):

@robot, I moved the discussion to the answer for better readability. Also you can accept it if you like.

Different blocks can be mapped to different SM's and hence executed in parallel. But, internally, blocks consist of warps which are scheduled for execution on an SM one at a time (on 1.x devices). However, the graphics hardware can switch between different warps with 0 overhead (owing to static register allocation). Therefore usually instructions from different warps (and possibly from different blocks) exist in the SM's pipeline at different stages.

Active warps are those that are ready to execute, i.e. not waiting on a barrier, memory access and do not have register dependencies (like read-after-write). I am not sure how the hardware chooses the next warp to execute. Propabably warps are prioritized by "age" (waiting time) and other factors to prevent starvation.

Concerning your questions:

1. on 1.x devices there could be at most 768 threads per SM , i.e. 24 warps/SM. On 2.x and higher, we have up to 1536 threads/48 warps per SM (depending on the register usage)
2. if there are 10 SMs per GPU, and you have enough registers/shared memory to run 24 warps per SM, then there could be at most 24*10 active warps per GPU. Though, it is rarely the case that all warps are active at the same time since most of them will be waiting for memory access/register dependencies or barriers, depending on your program logic. Remark that, the actual execution of an instruction (not scheduling!) can take up to 22 cycles on 1.x devices hence a warp will be inactive until the instruction completes.

Comment: @  asm    :thanks for your reply. I'm getting cleared about the warp, but still I want to know following:
What is 0 overhead?

Comment: zero overhead just means that context switch between warps in the SM is almost for free (does not induce additional cost). This is because each thread has its own copy of physical registers (static allocation). Hence, when the hardware needs to switch from one warp to another, there is no need to save/restore a register set from the memory as opposed to other architectures like x86 where there is just one set of registers used by all threads

Comment: @    asm   :   If you can please let me know whether my thinking is in right direction? 
Following my 1st question of this post, say 
1)there are 256/32=8 warps per SM and thus 8*3 = 24 warps/SM; (max 768 threads/SM); 
2)let there are 10 SMs total per GPU.
3)& let there are different time stages of GPU program execution, say time t0, t1, t2, t3, t4, etc..
Then at time t0, only 1 warp{(32 threads)(of any SM)} is executed on single SM, and active warps per SM are 23 on single SM and active warps per GPU are 23*10 (for all SMs), which can be switched by hardware.

Comment: @   asm    :   Ok. But as you told that utmost 24*10 will be the active warps at a time, though practically difficult to achieve and rarely achieved, I understood. Also< I understood, instruction will be executed taking 22 cycles and thus warp will be inactive until instruction completes; but how many warps execute the instruction and how many remain inactive during 22 cycles period time? If you can give an example please.